# how application user select that is he like to receive notification or not in android using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

In my application i can send notification to all users by FCM Console.
Now i want  that users select that they like to receive notifications or not , and only users that like it receive notifications.

please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`CheckBox`** for the user to set if he wanted to receive notifications or not and save it in **`Preference`**.

Example:-

Place A **`CheckBox`** In **`Activity/Fragment`**, And ask them if they want to receive notifications.

And Add This Code In Your **`Activity/Fragment`** *`java`* class.

```
    /*Global Variables*/
    public static final String PREFS_NAME ="com.pakage.appname";
    public static final String SHOULD_NOTIFY= "ShouldNotify";
    /*Global Variables*/

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)  findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
              if(isChecked)
                { 
                  setShouldNotifyInPref(true);
                }
              else 
                { 
                  setShouldNotifyInPref(false);
                } 
           }
       }
    );
```

And Now The Main Login Code:-

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + remoteMessage);
        if(getShouldNotifyFromPref())
           {
            //User Wants To Receive Notification
              showNotification();
           }
         else
          {
            //User Don't Want To Receive Notification
          }
    }
```

Function For Saving And Retrieving Data From Shared Preferences:-

**`Saving Data:-`**

```
    private void setShouldNotifyInPref(Boolean shouldNotify)
        {
        SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(SHOULD_NOTIFY, shouldNotify);
        editor.commit();
        }
```

**`Retrieving Data:-`**

```
private Boolean getShouldNotifyFromPref()
            {
            SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
            return pref.getBoolean(SHOULD_NOTIFY, null);
            }
```

Comment: Do Comment If You Face Any Problem @new_android